# Fermi coordinates on manifolds of negative sectional curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry

The Fermi coordinates are Riemannian geometry analogues of "cylindrical coordinates" in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Namely, take a unit-speed geodesic $\gamma \subset M^n$, and introduce coordinates in a tubular neighborhood of $\gamma$ as follows: a point $x$ in the tubular neighborhood has coordinates $(t, r, \omega)$, if $x$ lies on the geodesic hypersurface perpendicular to $\gamma(t)$, $r = d(x, \gamma(t))$ and $\omega \in S^{n - 2}$ is the obvious "angle".

It is known that a hyperbolic metric can be expressed as $ds^2 = \cosh^2r dt^2 + dr^2 + \sinh^2 rd\omega^2$ in  Fermi coordinates around a geodesic. My question is, how does the metric look in the general case of variable sectional curvature? I assume it should look like $ds^2 = \psi(r)^2 dt^2 + dr^2 + \phi(r)^2d\omega^2$, but what properties should $\phi$ and $\psi$ have? In particular, suppose we have a manifold of negative sectional curvature $K \leq -1$. Then can we necessarily say that $\phi \geq \sinh (r), \psi \geq \cosh (r)$? If yes, does this follow easily from some comparison geometry idea, or does one need to go about it the hard way, like computing the sectional curvature in these coordinates, and then use that to find the inequalities satisfied by $\psi$ and $\phi$?

In general too, I would like to learn more about Fermi coordinates, but I can find very little in the way of literature (looked at Petersen, Cheeger-Ebin and such standard references). Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

In general, $\psi$ and $\phi$ are functions of not just $r$ but also $\omega$ and $t$. There is no reason why the metric should look the same going in one direction away from $\gamma$ than a different direction. Unless you want to make that assumption.

Jacobi fields, which are infinitesimal variations of a geodesic, are the key here.

The idea here is to view your coordinates as giving you a 2-parameter family of geodesics, parameterized by $t$ and $\omega$. If you differentiate these geodesics with respect to $t$ and $\omega$, you get two Jacobi fields along each radial geodesic. A Jacobi field satisfies a second order ODE where the zero-th order coefficient is a sectional curvature. By using the Sturm comparison theorem, you can get what you want.

So I suggest reading the sections on Jacobi fields in either Petersen or Cheeger-Ebin and then returning to this question after that. Your question is a good exercise in the use of Jacobi fields.